# How to make a user stay logged in even after user exits the app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to know how to make a user stay logged in even after the app is exited in react native, I am using restAPI to make a user login into my app and it's working fine but my problem is when a user exits the app user is displayed the home again but I want the app to display the welcome screen instead if the user has already logged in my app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
Image,
TextInput,
Form,
TouchableHighlight,
ScrollView,
Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

// import hr from 'react-native-hr';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Hr from '../modules/hr.dist';
// import AndroidBackButton from 'react-native-android-back-button';

export default class Login extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)

this.state = {
  username: '',
  password: '',
}
}

_userLogin() { 
var pass = this.state.password;
var user = this.state.username;
if (pass && user) {
  fetch("http://www.amkwebsolutions.com/trades/rest_login/", {
    method: "POST", 
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'username': user, 
      'password': pass
    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    if (responseData.status==1) {
      this.props.navigator.replace({id: 'welcome', userData: {userId: responseData.user_id, userName: responseData.display_name, userAvatar: responseData.user_avtar} })
    } else {
      alert("Incorrect Username or Password")
    }
  }).done(); 
}
}

render() {
return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.header_main} >
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigator.push({id: 'home'})}><Icon name="arrow-left" size={20} color="black" /></TouchableHighlight>
          <Image source={{uri: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/vowelweb/image/upload/v1498114115/Logo_mqzlgt.png'}}   style={styles.header_logo}/>
          <Icon name="list-ul" size={20} color="black" />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.body_main}> 
          <Text style={styles.body_main_heading} >LOGIN</Text>
          <View style={styles.body_main_view_image}>
            <Image source={require("../images/Login.png")} style={styles.body_main_image}/>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.body_main_form}>
             <TextInput 
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              placeholder="Username" 
              returnKeyLabel = {"next"} 
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username:text})} 
              placeholderTextColor = "white"
              style={{height: 50, borderRadius: 45, marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20, marginTop: 0, backgroundColor: '#a6a6a8', fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', color: 'white', fontSize: 18, paddingLeft: 65,}} 
             />
             <TextInput 
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              secureTextEntry = {true}
              placeholder="Password"  
              placeholderTextColor = "white"
              returnKeyLabel = {"go"}
              onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password:password})} 
              style={{height: 50, borderRadius: 45, marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20, marginTop: 20, backgroundColor: '#a6a6a8', fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', color: 'white', fontSize: 18, paddingLeft: 65,}} 
             />
          </View>

        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#efeff2',}}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={() => this._userLogin()} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign in</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 0.6, backgroundColor: '#efeff2', flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight: 18,}}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigator.push({id: 'register'})}><Text style={{fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', color: 'black', fontSize: 16, paddingRight: 100,}}>Create Account</Text></TouchableHighlight>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigator.push({id: 'forgetpassword'})}><Text style={{fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', color: 'black', fontSize: 16,}}>Forgot Password ?</Text></TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 0.4, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight:10, backgroundColor: '#efeff2', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row',}}>
            <Hr lineStyle={{backgroundColor: "#a6a6a8"}} text='or' textStyle={{color: 'black', fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', fontSize: 16,}}/>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 20, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#efeff2',}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'black', fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', fontSize: 16, paddingRight: 35,}}>Connect with us</Text>
          <Image source={require("../images/Facebook.png")} style={{width: 50, height: 50, marginRight: 20,}} />
          <Image source={require("../images/Tumblr.png")} style={{width: 50, height: 50, marginRight: 20,}} />
          <Image source={require("../images/Google.png")} style={{width: 50, height: 50,}} />
        </View>
    </View>
);
}
}


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 },
header_main: {
flex: 1.3, 
paddingLeft: 20, 
paddingRight:20, 
backgroundColor: 'white',
justifyContent: 'center',
flexDirection: 'row',
borderBottomWidth:1,
alignItems: 'center',
},

header_logo: { 
flex:1,
width:350,
height:100,
resizeMode:'contain',
marginRight: 12,
marginLeft: 12,
},

body_main: {
flex: 4, 
backgroundColor: '#efeff2',
justifyContent: 'center'

},
body_main_heading: {
textAlign:'center',
fontSize:24,
paddingTop:10,
fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold',
color: 'black',
},

body_main_view_image: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#efeff2',
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'center',
paddingTop: 0,
},
body_main_image: {
width:null,
height:null,
resizeMode:'contain',
paddingLeft: 50, 
paddingRight:50
},
body_main_input: {
},
buttonText: {
fontSize: 18,
color: 'white',
alignSelf: 'center',
fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold',
},
button: {
height: 50,
backgroundColor: '#217821',
borderColor: '#217821',
borderWidth: 1,
borderRadius: 45,
marginTop: 20,
alignSelf: 'stretch',
justifyContent: 'center',
marginLeft: 20, 
marginRight: 20,
},
});
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference

Comment: Store some value in the shared preference of Android and UserDefaults for iOS. These values persist even after app is killed. And whenever the app is launched check that if the particular value exists then user must be logged in else behave as no user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store user credentials and check in main activity, follow this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm